# zip to file with extension other than ".zip"

Tags: zip

`zip -r ./compressed.resource ./file1.js ./file1.js.map`

I'm trying to compress 2 files into an achieve that does end in `.zip`

However, when I run this I get an error:

```
> zip -r ./compressed.resource ./file1.js ./file1.js.map

        zip warning: missing end signature--probably not a zip file (did you
        zip warning: remember to use binary mode when you transferred it?)
        zip warning: (if you are trying to read a damaged archive try -F)

zip error: Zip file structure invalid (./compressed.resource)
```

is it possible to keep the `.resource` extension?

Comment: Could you do it in two steps? Make the zip and then rename it?

Comment: @music2myear ya, thats what I ended up doing... but I was just wondering if it could be done in one

Comment: How about using [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)?

Comment: @wysiwyg it's part of a build script so the goal was to make it as platform/configuration agnostic as possible.  Seems like the chaining of commands is the best answer

Comment: Using “Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008), by Info-ZIP” I can do what you want with no error messages, both with new and existing archives. I performed those tests on Cygwin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done as a one-liner, but not in a cross-platform way, and not as a single command.

Zip is integrated into many systems, but not usually as a discrete executable, and the commands will not be consistent across platforms.

However, one thing that will be consistent is that Zip compresses files, and it does not rename file extensions.

In order to both compress AND rename you will need to use two discrete commands.

Answer (score -1):

Since you did not provide any information about the OS, version of software etc. I just assume you are using a recent Linux distro. Though zip is a archive format, it does only allow files with the .zip ending.  Use a different archiver like `tar` to make and tell it to apply compression (see the manpage, it's really insightful). Tar will allow you to name the output what ever you want it, if you supply all parameters it needs. That's how you get .tgz bzw. tar.gz or tar.bz2 or what ever.

Comment: But that’s wrong. ZIP *is* an archive format. It commonly uses Deflate compression.

Comment: I thought I read somewhere that zip was part of windows, osx and linux by default.  This is part of an NPM build script so it ideally will run on any platform.

Comment: @DanielB you are actually right on ZIP being a archive format. Corrected that. Still my point remains that tar can do what OP is asking for.